# vim simple mapping of shift key

Tags: vim

I am trying to modify my vimrc in the following way:

`map <S-Up> <C-U>`

`map <S-Down> <C-D>`

`map <S-.> G`

in order to :

move the screen up by pressing Shift+Up

move the screen down by pressing Shift+Down

go to a specific line by typing the line number then Shift+. (instead of typing line number then G)

But none of those mappings work.
I've browsed google and SO to figure out what I'm doing wrong but no luck.
Anyone can give any pointer?

Comment: Vim can't see those combos. It *may* see the escape sequence generated by those combos, though, so you *may* be able to use those instead. In insert mode, what's the output of `<C-v><S-Up>`, `<C-v><S-Down>`, and `<C-v><S-.>` (press Ctrl+V then your combo)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<S-.>` (assuming an US-English keyboard layout that has `.` and `>` on the same key), you can just write `>`. Then, the mapping will work.

In the graphical GVIM, your `<S-Up>` will work as well. In the terminal, things are complicated. For me (*gnome-terminal*), pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> does not send anything to Vim (to check, press `:<C-v>`, then the keys, and observe what gets inserted literally). For (unshifted) `<Up>`, I get `^[OA`, the expected keycode.

So, if this is mostly about the terminal, it may make sense to select different (more ordinary) keys (cursor keys are frowned upon by Vim users, anyway :-).

Comment: thx for your reply. I now changed `map <S-.> G` to `map g G` and it does work as intended. However regading the movement remap I tried the more conservative`nmap <C-k> <C-U>` and `nmap <C-j> <C-D>` and they still dont work! What am I doing wrong this time?